# Open html document in chrome from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome

In Eclipse, when I right click a HTML document and select "Open with..." I am presented with a list of options including the internal browser available in Eclipse. What I want to do is open the document in Google Chrome. I can select external program and select Chrome but I have to do this each time. Is there a way to have Google Chrome automatically available as one of the options when I right click the document? Is there also a way to have Debug or Run configured to use Chrome as the default app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser -> Use external web browser and select Chrome